# Risk of sharing p12 files for iOS development

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, ios, apple, xcode

When we have only the individual Apple developer account and want to develop with a team, I believe we should share the p12 file with other developers. Then what will happen?

The private key differs from the one for distribution, so the cracker can't release apps to attack. Currently, I found only one issue.

- If the code is leaked, the cracker can run the app as a developer.

But, of course, the most critical problem is leaking the code.

Are there other problems? Please tell me your opinions! And please correct my knowledge if it's wrong!